# Select distinct type, max(date), ordernumber and articles by using location variable - SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Ok... I spent now 2 days writing, rewriting, rethinking and I'm kind of stuck here.

I'll try to explane in "simple mode"

I have a table containing history of orders picked from a warehouse.

Sometimes you find things "stored" where they "shouldnt" be "stored" and the idea was to build a report that shows the user:

Which in-store order AND picking order where last to visit this location. Not only ordernumber but also all articles on those orders.

So by adding address to a variable I would like to have result showing that ”this” order number was last visiting ”this” location and these articles was on ”that” order.
Same goes with other order type.

Example (simplified)
`Type   OrderNo ArtNo   DateTime    Address
A   111 10  2014-09-01 11:08:09.000 05-009-09-09
E   222 20  2014-09-01 11:08:09.000 02-021-02-01
A   333 30  2014-10-04 11:08:09.000 01-001-01-01
E   222 60  2014-08-01 11:08:09.000 02-056-02-07
A   444 90  2014-07-01 11:08:09.000 01-022-01-01
A   444 40  2014-07-01 11:08:09.000 01-056-02-01
E   777 70  2014-10-02 11:08:09.000 04-102-12-04
E   777 80  2014-10-02 11:08:09.000 01-001-01-01
A   555 50  2014-10-01 11:08:09.000 02-099-07-01
E   777 10  2014-10-02 11:08:09.000 03-011-03-02`

Order number 333 is the last order visiting address 01-001-01-01 for order type A and order number 777 is the last order number visiting address 01-001-01-01 for order type E.

My SQL should give me result:

```
A   333 30  2014-10-01 11:08:09.000 01-001-01-01  
E   777 70  2014-10-01 11:08:09.000 04-102-12-04  
E   777 80  2014-10-01 11:08:09.000 01-001-01-01  
E   777 10  2014-10-01 11:08:09.000 03-011-03-02
```

Based on my variable 01-001-01-01

The important columns are:

```
Ordertype, orderNumber, articleNo, dateTime and adress
```

Adress is tricky because it is stored in 4 different columns:

```
shelfName, tray, tpos, depth
```

I solved this with

```
Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), shelfname), 2) + '-' +
Right(replicate('0', 3) + CONVERT(varchar(3), tray), 3) + '-' +
Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), tpos), 2) + '-' +
Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), depth), 2)
```

Which results in

```
02-035-09-02
```

So my idea was to

```
declare @var1 varchar(12)
set @var1='02-035-09-02'
```

to be able to find last in-store and out-store orders that had something to do with that location.

```
select 
    .... ...
where 
    @var1 = Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), shelfname), 2) + '-' +
            Right(replicate('0', 3) + CONVERT(varchar(3), tray), 3) + '-' +
            Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), tpos), 2) + '-' +
            Right(replicate('0',2)+CONVERT(varchar(2),depth), 2)
```

But I only want 1 of ordertype E and 1 of ordertype A (sort of distinct) (se sample below)

Sample data

```
OrderType (varchar) | orderNumber (varchar) | ArticleNo (varchar) | dateTime | adress  

E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:08:09.000 04-030-12-04  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:08:03.000 04-030-10-02  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:07:04.000 02-020-13-04  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:06:48.000 03-016-08-02  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:06:38.000 04-015-05-03  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:06:28.000 03-016-04-04  
E   4967    14608   2014-10-08 11:06:13.000 02-020-12-03  
A   1942513 10134   2014-10-08 10:54:53.000 05-086-01-03  
A   1942517 10848   2014-10-08 10:53:52.000 05-091-05-03  
A   1942517 10103   2014-10-08 10:52:10.000 05-015-14-01  
A   1942517 10103   2014-10-08 10:51:49.000 05-015-10-02  
A   1942514 10995   2014-10-08 10:50:23.000 05-027-11-01  
A   1942517 10142   2014-10-08 10:48:54.000 05-040-17-03  
A   1942519 40180   2014-10-08 10:48:33.000 01-052-14-03  
A   1942519 40180   2014-10-08 10:48:10.000 01-033-18-02  
A   1942517 10142   2014-10-08 10:47:44.000 05-041-04-02  
A   1942513 10570   2014-10-08 10:46:47.000 05-052-05-03  
A   1942513 50019   2014-10-08 10:45:01.000 05-065-02-04  
A   1942513 11726   2014-10-08 10:41:22.000 01-040-16-02  
A   1942517 10848   2014-10-08 10:39:07.000 04-011-05-03  
A   1942514 10995   2014-10-08 10:38:15.000 01-057-22-03  
E   4964    30989   2014-10-08 10:32:11.000 01-058-03-02  
E   4964    17301   2014-10-08 10:31:58.000 01-054-32-02  
E   4964    3970    2014-10-08 10:31:48.000 01-054-14-02  
E   4964    17823   2014-10-08 10:31:14.000 01-020-31-03  
A   1942421 14782   2014-10-08 10:22:06.000 02-033-08-01  
A   1942282 14992   2014-10-08 10:20:50.000 02-032-13-01  
A   1942421 14585   2014-10-08 10:19:51.000 02-029-01-03
```

All column names in my example is made up to make it easier to understand.

This wasn't easy to explain... Let me know if I should provide any test data

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you want. Could you provide more information? Preferably some test data, and the desired output based on that test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some input from mxix. I have now solved it.

```
declare @adress varchar(12)  
set @adress='01-070-13-01'
select articleNo, OrderNo, type, dateTime, Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), genr), 2) + '-' +Right(replicate('0', 3) + CONVERT(varchar(3), tsnr), 3) + '-' +Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), lkvon), 2) + '-' +Right(replicate('0',2)+CONVERT(varchar(2),favon), 2)  
from myTable where OrderNo in 
(select
T.orderNo
from myTable  T
inner join (
select 
    typ,
    MAX([dateTime]) LastEntry
from myTable
where @adress = Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), shelfname), 2) + '-' +Right(replicate('0', 3) + CONVERT(varchar(3), tray), 3) + '-' +Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), tpos), 2) + '-' +Right(replicate('0',2)+CONVERT(varchar(2),depth), 2)
group by type
) Filter ON
Filter.LastEntry = T.[dateTime] AND
Filter.type = T.type
)

order by dateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Last entry for an address for each Type. did i understodd it correctly?

```
select
    T.*
from sampleTable  T
inner join (
    select 
        OrderType,
        MAX([dateTime]) LastEntry
    from sampleTable
    where 
        adress = Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), shelfname), 2) + '-' +
                Right(replicate('0', 3) + CONVERT(varchar(3), tray), 3) + '-' +
                Right(replicate('0', 2) + CONVERT(varchar(2), tpos), 2) + '-' +
                Right(replicate('0',2)+CONVERT(varchar(2),depth), 2)
    group by
        OrderType
) Filter ON
    Filter.LastEntry = T.[Datetime] AND
    Filter.OrderType = T.OrderType
```

Comment: Last entry(s) for an address for each type yes. All articles belonging to that order number that match last entry

Comment: The SQL you provide above works BUT i get only 1 article / order. I need also remaining lines = to the order number. I'll think I can fix it my self. Thx so far